# SQL Query giving error

Tags: sql, sqlite

What is wrong with this query :

```
SELECT count() as total_students 
FROM student_information;

SELECT
    (
        SELECT student_project_marks 
        from students_project 
        WHERE student_project_id=student_information.student_project_id 
    ) 
    + student_assignment_marks 
    + student_exam_marks AS total_marks 
FROM student_information  
ORDER BY total_marks DESC;

UPDATE student_information
SET (
        SELECT student_grade 
        FROM student_information 
        LIMIT 0.1*total_students 
        ORDER BY total_marks DESC
    )="A";
```

Iam trying to select `0.1*total_students` number of students ordered by their total marks obtained and update their grades.... Top 10% will be awarded as A.
I am getting error :
`syntax error near '('`

I have 2 tables :
created them via following query:

```
create table if not exists student_information (
student_name varchar(80),
student_roll_num int primary key,
student_email varchar(64),
student_assignment_marks int(2) check(student_assignment_marks<=30),
student_exam_marks int(2) check(student_exam_marks<=50),
student_project_id varchar(25),
student_grade varchar(2)
)

create table if not exist students_project (
 student_project_id varchar(25),
 student_project_title varchar(25),
 student_project_marks int(2) check(student_project_marks>=0 and student_project_marks<=20)
 )
```

Marks in the project is accessed from the `student_project` table via the `student_project_id`.

Now how do I award the grade based on the total marks... 
Top 10% have to be awarded A, next 10% B and so on... 
I know how to calculate total marks... 
I have writen a query like this:

```
select student_roll_num, 
 (SELECT student_project_marks 
  from students_project 
  WHERE student_project_id=student_information.student_project_id )+
student_assignment_marks+student_exam_marks as total_marks from student_information;
```

It works.

Comment: I'm not sure you can do math in a `LIMIT` clause in any RDBMS.  And wouldn't you need to declare variables in order to store off values?

Comment: Your update statement has several issues. It is not clear to me what you are trying to do.

Comment: You're also trying to update only the top 10% students by _count_, when this needs to be factored by grade, too - what happens if 15% of the students get an identical top grade?  You'd be penalizing a 'random' 5% of the population.

Comment: And the relationship between `students_project` and `student_information` seems backwards.

Answer (score 2):

This is not even approximately correct SQL.  Also, it's not clear *how* you're executing these statements (from a console, from a program, etc).

A few comments to help get you on your way:

1. SQL does not "remember" the results of previous statements from one statement to the next.  Therefore, your calculation of `total_students` in the first SQL statement has no connection with your attempt to actually use that value in your third statement.  Similarly, your attempt to derive `total_marks` in the second query is not available in your third query.
2. Your second statement only makes sense if the internal query is guaranteed to produce only a single record for each row in student_information.  I'm reasonable certain that what you're attempting to do would be better done using a JOIN rather than a sub-query.
3. The third query (UPDATE) is the one that's furthest away from SQL.  UPDATE operates on one or more columns in a table.  Each column is assigned a new value.  The columns it operates on must be literally named with the correct identifiers.  You can use a sub-query on the *right* side of the equals sign, but not on the left (although you don't have any reason to use one here).  The conditions for the set of rows on which to operate belong in a WHERE clause at the end of the UPDATE statement, not within any kind of sub-query.
4. Guessing at your intent, I think you probably need to SUM or AVG the grades from student_projects (assuming each student has several projects to consider), and there's no aggregation in any of your queries.

Comment: thanks for you info... I wasn't knowing this... 
Actually I want to update the `grade` of the student based on the total marks... I can calculate the total marks (I have created the query which is executing and giving correct results), but the problem lies in selecting to 10% student and update their grades as `A`... I am sorry If this question is too silly, but I am new to SQL...

Comment: Please post the structure of your tables and describe how they relate to each other (that is, which tables are in one-to-many relationships with the others).